# Firebase: Budget and Daily Spending Limit

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, app-engine-flexible

I've set a daily spending limit for my **Firebase** project.

Inside the same project, I added a NodeJS App Engine app.

So I've received this warning:

[image]

In that case, all spending limits are ignored?
If Firebase goes to $99999 it won't be stopped?

Thanks..

Answer (score 1):

The warning you receives reflects reality, if your app is deployed in the App Engine Flexible environment. To avoid $99999 surprises, you can create a budget for a GCP project to protect somehow your bill and monitor all of your Google Cloud Platform charges from one place. To see how you create a budget, you may have a look at the "Managing GCP Projects, App Engine Applications, and Billing" documentation [page](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/flexible/java/managing-projects-apps-billing#creating_budgets_and_setting_alerts).

Comment: But the Firebase is a different API then my NodeJS server.. It won't cut calls to the Firebase api?

Comment: You can configure your NodeJS server in accordance with your needs, so it should not negatively interfere with your Firebase usage. Is your NodeJS server actually deployed in the Flexible Environment?