# Is it possible to set some kind of firestore read/write quotas to avoid overspending when using Blaze plan?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have upgraded to the firebase Blaze plan since I want to use cloud functions with nodejs 10 and the Pubsub schedule functions but I am a bit scared of overspending by mistake once I reach the free quota.

I am already aware that I can set up some budget alerts to monitor my monthly spending but I am more looking for a safety net solution in case my usage of Firestore suddenly goes through the roof because of an error in the code (infinite loop for example, like it happened to me last week) or even some kind of DDoS attack.

The [documentation](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/quotas#set_spending_limits) mentions a daily spending limit which is exactly what I was looking for but it seems to be deprecated since end of 2019. **Is there a way to set some kind of quotas for Firestore (read/write per day or minutes) in a similar way to how we can set quotas for the number of invocations of cloud functions?**

I find it hard to believe that Gcloud removed the daily spending limit without offering any alternative as it could, in case of human errors, bugs, or even attacks, leave independent developers with gigantic bills they can't afford. I am seriously considering downgrading back to the free plan.

Is there any alternative solution to cap Firestore spending or usage?

Answer (score 0):

It is not possible to set a quota limit on the Firebase operations. This is a known issue but you can mitigate it by setting alerts on the GCP project. There is more information from a Googler in https://stackoverflow.com/a/52325021/6003934